# Why has my numpy correlation code stopped working?

Tags: python, ubuntu

np.corrcoef has stopped working.

It worked until a few hours ago then mysteriously stopped working. I tried converting all numbers to floats, then all numbers to int, but still np.corrcoef does not work.

```
correlation_30_16 = np.corrcoef(final_output_row_30,   final_output_row_16)
print()
print('correlation_30_16 = ', correlation_30_16)
```

gives me

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/robert/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2400
    c /= stddev[:, None]
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

correlation_30_16 =  [[nan nan]
 [nan nan]]
```

I am trying to correlate list 30 with lists 16.

```
final_output_row_30 =  [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
final_output_row_16 =  [178, 178, 178, 178, 178]
```

I used to get outputs like this:

```
12_34 correlation_f_alleles  =  [[ 1.         -0.90876454]
 [-0.90876454  1.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working correctly. The problem is your input values. It is impossible to calculate a correlation if you only ever observe the same X and Y values.

Try for example `np.corrcoef([0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25],   [177, 178, 179, 180, 181])`, this will (corretly) give you a perfect correlation of 1.0 every time.

Below is the formula for the correlation cofficient.  You are ending up with zeros below the line since in each case xi equals the avarage over all x's (same for y).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

np.corrcoev calculates the correlation coefficient matrix. This calculation includes a division by the covariance of both voctors which is zero in your case. An error is thrown since the correlation coefficient is mathematically undefined, c.f.:

`np.cov([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], [178, 178, 178, 178, 178])  # covariance is all zeros.`